# Errors on installing PCL 1.8 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-16.04, pcl

I got the executable PCL 1.8 from **[HERE](https://larrylisky.com/2016/11/03/point-cloud-library-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/#comment-3100)** and installed it. But when tried to run an example demo, it complaints: How to fix it?

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfig.cmake:45 (message):
  PCL can not be found on this machine
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfig.cmake:774 (pcl_report_not_found)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error after installing from the same source. I finally tracked down the error to a wrong entry in the PCLConfig.cmake file. The PCL_ROOT variable there is beeing set to /usr/local, while the files were actually installed into /usr. Changing this variable resolved the problem for me.